# Can a Power Word spell be cast silently?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, spells

*Power word stun* and *power word kill*, having only a verbal component, are fascinating, in that the intent appears to be that their power is tied to the words in question. What happens if you take out those words, through the use of the Silent Spell metamagic feat?

Comment: [Mandatoory OOTS comic](http://oots.wikia.com/wiki/Power_Word:_Annoy)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There is nothing special about these spells that prevents you from applying the Silent Spell feat, by casting them with a higher spell slot, or the equivalent of such. They still require concentration and the appropriate action to cast, however.